# Play youtube video in slider and pause slider

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

I am making my custom jQuery slider. I want to pause slider while youtube video is playing. So I need a reference or any help so I can complete my slider.

Comment: What is your question? What kind of reference are you looking for? What have you done so far, and do you have any example code? Right now you're not really asking a question, but just saying that you need a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the YouTube API you can stop your slider when the video is on playing mode. Try to play a little bit with this > https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo?hl=fr and here you can find a great example of what you need > https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#chromeless_player

You can get the current event of your video and then pause/stop your slider.

Let me know if you need more details about this issue.

Comment: Hi Ussama thnx for your help. I can pause slideshow when video is playing but can not pause slideshow when video is getting load first-time after click on play button.Currently It moves to next slide and it pause slideshow when video is ready to play.

Comment: So you just have to pause the slideshow when you click on the play button using a simple `.click()` mouse event.

And you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're using an embedded player using the iframe api:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

If not, I strongly suggest you do so. It'll allow you to listen to the player's state change event and execute a function when it starts playing.

Taking the page's example, in the "Get started" chapter, I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        // Pause your slideshow
    }
}
```

Modify the parameters for the player to your liking and write your own code to stop the slideshow in the onPlayerStateChange function. There are other states that you might want to check in that same function, described in the "Events" chapter, such as the paused or ended states.